# Spring Data JPA Setup not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I made a simple java program with Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + Microsoft SQL Server. When I run the program I get the following exception and I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 19 more
```

This is my main method:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Context.class);

        NameRepository repo = context.getBean(NameRepository.class);

        List<Name> names = repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

This is my context config:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("test")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("test")
public class Context {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxx;instanceName=xxxxxx;databaseName=Test");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxxxxxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxxxxxx");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("test");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My entity class:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
public class Name {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Name() {

    }
}
```

My Repository interface:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface NameRepository extends JpaRepository<Name, Long> {
}
```

And of course my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What happens when you search this site for "NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()" ?

Comment: @NeilStockton I tried to use Spring 4.2.9 togehter with hibernate-core 5.1 and 5.0. Did not work. 

Answer (score 0):

I think you need hibernate-entitymanager dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Also as far as i know hibernate-entitymanager is deprecated. The code moved into hibernate-core.

Comment: After you bulid with maven and go to your /target, and does the lib folder contain more than one hibernate-core jar? And what is the version?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no lib folder.

Comment: /target/<your-artficat-name-version>/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The target folder only conatins the folders "classes", "generated-sources" and "maven-status". There is no lib folder in any folder.

Comment: Ok i forgot this is a jar not war.. Please run this: mvn -X clean package. Then place the output somewhere like Dropbox and place a link here. Lets see whats going on there

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully remember but when I was working with Spring data jpa, I remember having trouble accessing the beans in my system in the main method. What I think I remember doing was using @Autowired in a method in the Main class that takes the NameRepository as a parameter. Sorry I don't remember much.

```
@AutoWired
public void findAllAtInit(NameRepository repo){
 List<Name> names = repo.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my pom.xml. It works fine now.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```